# Group: only a BranchGroup node may be added

Tags: java, java-3d

I'm trying to put a Behaviour into a BranchGroup but when I run the programm, it returns me this error:

"Exception in thread "Thread-1" javax.media.j3d.RestrictedAccessException: Group: only a BranchGroup node may be added"

I have to say that I put those setCapabilities:

```
    ramaVisible = new BranchGroup();
    ramaVisible.setCapability(BranchGroup.ALLOW_DETACH);
    ramaVisible.setCapability(BranchGroup.ALLOW_CHILDREN_WRITE);
    ramaVisible.setCapability(BranchGroup.ALLOW_CHILDREN_READ);
    ramaVisible.setCapability(BranchGroup.ALLOW_CHILDREN_EXTEND);
    ramaVisible.setCapability(BranchGroup.ALLOW_BOUNDS_READ);
    ramaVisible.setCapability(BranchGroup.ALLOW_BOUNDS_WRITE);
```

and this is what I do to put the behaviour into a BranchGroup

```
    Colisiones behaviourColision = new Colisiones(this.ramaVisible,this,this.juego);
    behaviourColision.setSchedulingBounds(new BoundingSphere());
    this.ramaVisible.addChild(behaviourColision);
```

I'm developing this program in Java3D

Answer (score 0):

You may find some additional information [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423848/add-a-object-to-a-branchgroup-after-the-group-is-added-to-a-locale-or-a-simpleun).

Unfortunately I don't believe that's enough to solve the problem, but it put me on the right track.

Here is my own example of how I resolved this issue.

```
BranchGroup scene = new BranchGroup();
BranchGroup content = new BranchGroup();
content.setCapability(BranchGroup.ALLOW_DETACH);
content.setCapability(Group.ALLOW_CHILDREN_EXTEND);
scene.setCapability(BranchGroup.ALLOW_DETACH);
scene.setCapability(Group.ALLOW_CHILDREN_EXTEND);
scene.setCapability(Group.ALLOW_CHILDREN_WRITE);
scene.compile();

//add the initial set of children to "content"...
content.addChild(directionalLight);

scene.addChild(content);

//initialize a SimpleUniverse object...

universe.addBranchGraph(scene);
```

Later at runtime:

```
content.detach();
content.addChild(newChild);
scene.addChild(content);
```

I'm not sure if there is a simpler way to do it, but unfortunately only setting the capabilities at creation time did not suffice. And although you have to detach and reparent a group, that's presumably better than adding a new BranchGroup, which is another hack that would do the trick.