# Add a Object to a BranchGroup after the group is added to a Locale or a SimpleUniverse

Tags: java, java-3d

Consider a simple code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.media.j3d.*;
import javax.vecmath.Color3f;
import javax.vecmath.*;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.*;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final SimpleUniverse universe = new SimpleUniverse();
    final BranchGroup group = new BranchGroup();

    TriangleArray triangle = new TriangleArray(3, TriangleArray.COORDINATES);
    triangle.setCoordinates(0, new Point3f[]{
        new Point3f(-0.3f,     0, -1),
        new Point3f(    0, -0.3f, -1),
        new Point3f(    0,     0, -1),
    });
    group.addChild(new Shape3D(triangle));

    universe.addBranchGraph(group);

    TriangleArray triangle1 = new TriangleArray(3, TriangleArray.COORDINATES);
    triangle1.setCoordinates(0, new Point3f[]{
        new Point3f(0.3f,    0, -1),
        new Point3f(   0, 0.3f, -1),
        new Point3f(   0,    0, -1),
    });
    group.addChild(new Shape3D(triangle1));
  }
}
```

Before adding `group` to the `universe`, I add a triangle `triangle` to it and it works fine.

After adding the group to the universe, I want to add another triangle `triangle1`. However, I get the error

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.media.j3d.RestrictedAccessException: Group: only a BranchGroup node may be added
        at javax.media.j3d.Group.addChild(Group.java:284)
        at Main.<init>(Main.java:34)
        at Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

So I set the `BranchGroup`'s `ALLOW_DETACH` capability, remove it from the locale, add the object, then re-add the group to the universe:

```
// On initialization
group.setCapability(BranchGroup.ALLOW_DETACH);

// ...

// Adding another triangle
group.detach();
group.addChild(new Shape3D(triangle1));
universe.addBranchGraph(group);
```

However, that appears to be unnecessarily complex. Is there any other, better way to add the Object?

Comment: Look at this example: http://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.4.0/javax/media/j3d/doc-files/HelloUniverse.html Look at this schema too: http://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.4.0/javax/media/j3d/doc-files/intro.gif Which kind of object do you add into a BranchGroup? Do you use Java3D 1.6.0?

Comment: @gouessej The example you provided add the BranchGroup to the Universe at last, my question ask about add a object **after** the BranchGroup is added. I just add a ColorCube and I use Java3D 1.6.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call BranchGroup.setCapability(Group.ALLOW_CHILDREN_EXTEND) very early and you should be allowed to add new children even after the BranchGroup is added.

Comment: "An important characteristic of all scene graph objects is that they can only be accessed or modified during the creation of a scene graph, except where explicitly allowed". Java3D is a very rigid scenegraph API. If you need something flexible and fast, look at JogAmp's Ardor3D Continuation, JMonkeyEngine or LibGDX. To be honest, I'm responsible for engine support in the JogAmp community. If you really want to add anything into a BranchGroup, you have to use my trick and you have to detach the BranchGroup so that it is no longer "live".